# MySQL reverse match

Tags: mysql

I have the following script which shows me data for records that are both in the ADATA table and CDATA table, matched by first and last name (the only fields I have which are the same in both tables):

```
SELECT
c.asdf AS ASDF,
CONCAT(a.genr, ' ' ,a.firstname, ' ' ,a.lastname) AS Name,
a.rcvdate AS Report_Date,
c.enroll AS Enroll_Date,
a.cvb AS CVB,
c.pctcomp AS Percent_Complete

FROM
adata a,
cdatas c

WHERE
a.firstname = c.firstname
AND a.lastname = c.lastname
```

What I need to do from here is get a list of records that are in ADATA but NOT in CDATA, and also the records in CDATA that are NOT in ADATA. I tried all different variation of using `NOT` in the WHERE part of the script but that always gave me 800 -- the total number of records in ADATA (the CDATA table only has 130 records).

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> create table a (x int);
mysql> create table b (y int);
mysql> insert into a values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
mysql> insert into b values (2), (4), (6);
mysql> select x from a where not x in (select y from b);
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    5 |
+------+
mysql> select y from b where not y in (select x from a);
+------+
| y    |
+------+
|    6 |
+------+
```

Comment: IN and NOT IN are not as efficient as joins; avoid them if you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT columns
FROM
    adata a
    LEFT JOIN cdatas c ON (a.firstname = c.firstname AND a.lastname = c.lastname)
WHERE
    c.asdf IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT columns
FROM
    cdatas c
    LEFT JOIN adata a ON (c.firstname = a.firstname AND c.lastname = a.lastname)
WHERE
    a.cvb IS NULL
```

Comment: This syntax ran correctly, but I'm a bit confused by the output. It gave me 771 records (which sounds about right), however 674 of the records have 'asdf', 'enroll date', and 'percent complete' saying NULL. The rest have 'name', 'report date', and 'cvb' as NULL. Can you tell me what this means?